# Is storing diluted (~1M) sulfuric acid, HCl, NaOH, etc. in plastic PET bottles a bad idea?

Tags: safety

Do I really need glass bottles if the acids and NaOH is so diluted? I thought plastics dont really react with acids. And I already have them in plastic bottles (probably a different kind).

Thanks

Comment: Concentrated $HCl$ is roughly 10 M, so its pH should be -1 (in practice it is higher as at such concentration the dissociation of HCl is suppressed). Roughly same is of 1M NaOH. I would not store this liquids in PET. However, storing this liquids in polypropylene or polyethylene is OK.

Comment: Actually, it is a good idea to store $NaOH$ in polyethylene/polypropylene/teflon. Strong bases slowly eat glass away. As my buddy with great practice said, even concentrated ammonia solutions eat glass.

Comment: In any case, do not use drink or food containers to store chemicals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you can find thorough and clear instructions about using plastic bottles for acids and bases:

http://www.corning.com/lifesciences/emea/en/technical_resources/product_guid/bottles/material.aspx

A common rule is to not store strong acids and bases (like sulfuric and hydrochloric acids, and NaOH) in plastic bottles if you are not sure about the type of plastics.

Polystyrene bottles are OK for strong alkali.

Here is a PDF document on this topic:

http://csmedia2.corning.com/lifesciences/media/pdf/PSUG_Storage_Bottles_CLS_GL_025.pdf

Comment: The best bet for storage of acids and bases is ACIDS: glass, teflon, and polyethylene (LDPE or HDPE); BASES: Teflon or polyethylene